# Eclipse not recognizing breakpoints

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am having this weird bug in eclipse when setting my breakpoints it just over lap it without passing through the breakpoint where the method is called. I know it keeps bypassing it for the reason that the only method that is being called is on a lot of breakpoints.

Did anyone encounter this kind of problem or know a fix?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Restarted eclipse and this time I was able to debug properly. Strange bug I am uncertain of knowing the cause and effect.

Comment: @AsavPatel Because the OP can accept whatever he/she likes. And he/she likes his/her answer more.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that 'Run > Skip all breakpoints' is not enabled.

Comment: Somehow this was the case for me. I don't recall turning that on. Any idea , what could have caused `Skip all breakpoints` selected?

Comment: @SabirKhan In my case this most probably was just because accidentally hitting CTRL+ALT+B keyboard shortcut. Did not even know such existing. Never read the whole Eclipse manual :D

Answer (score 5):

there can be many many reasons:

The most common ones:

- .java and .class are out of sync
- wrong version of the runtime JVM
- debug information removed from the generated class
- classpath mismatch, for instance eclipse compiles into bin/ and your runtime picks up classes from classes/  (this assumes, you also compile from the command line)
- Bad Eclipse installation

First try cleaning the project by using the clean function

> Project > clean...

Comment: Which means you need to make sure the breakpoints are compiled into your .class files.

Comment: Good answer. What would you recommend I do to fix?

Comment: Rebuild your project from sources. Validate compiler setting and paths

Comment: I love Project > Clean however after 5 times I am thinking my eclipse is dirty (If you know what I mean ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have any beans declared in xml file. If so please check if they are commented we need to uncomment them.

In my case i have a bean declaration in my xml file for that particular bean and it is not loaded at the time of server start. So my debug points are not enabled.

I have uncommented my bean entry then i am able to check debug points and it is working.

hope it will help.